# How to tell if a message mentions any user on the server?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to, with discord.js, tell if any given message mentions any user on the server.

Comment: Did you try [`Message#mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions)?

Answer (score 4):

[`Message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) is what you're looking for: you can either check `.users` or `.members`. If there's at least one element in one of these [collections](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection), then someone has been mentioned:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.mentions.members.first()) // there's at least one mentioned user
  else // there's no mentioned user
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a map of users and match with incoming messages

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const map = {}

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
        const users = msg.content.match(/@[a-z\d]+/ig)
        users.forEach((user) => {
            if (map[users.slice(1)]) {
                console.log(`${users.slice(1)} mentioned in server`)
            }
        })
    }
})   

client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval (function (){
        for(u in Bot.users){
            map[client.users[u].username] = true
        }
    }, 10000)
})

client.login('token')
```